# Drop and Inner shadow for button in javafx

Tags: button, javafx, dropshadow

I have a button in javafx and its pseudoclass .button:pressed is supposed to have a drop and an inner shadow. What I'm trying is

```
.button:pressed {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 10,0,0,1 ); 
    -fx-effect: innershadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.7) , 20,0,0,0 );
}
```

However, only the second effect seems to be applied to the button (actually, the effect whichever comes second will be applied). I've looked here: http://www.canoo.com/blog/2012/07/10/javafx-recipes-css-vs-code/?lang=de, but I don't see a difference to my approach.
Is there a way to apply two shadows to one button?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's currently not possible in Java 7 nor in Java 8 to chain effects or apply multiple effects via CSS. See the [Oracle CSS Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typeeffect).

The site you reference mentions it as well:

> Well at the moment it is not possible to chain effects in CSS which
>   means we only could apply one of the needed effects which would lead
>   to the following result for the code above…

Answer (score 1):

Can't mix types (drop & inner), not even comma separated... I've tried, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I get the Key of your Question.
The commants looks obviously right ...

Might it depends on the given dropshadow parameters.

To understand the parameters you can use the [oracle-documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/DropShadow.html).
To find another rgba color you can use these [rgba color chooser tool](http://www.css3-generator.de/rgba.html).

Even If I havent a directly awnser for you, I hope the links help you to get a better overview about the css comment dropshadow.

cheerse 
Tobi

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not the point. I understand what I'm doing, the only thing that confuses me is that not both effects are applied to the button which is what I want. Also I think it doesn't depend on the parameters.